# Multi-feature padding for LSTM

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, rnn, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train a LSTM on an NER dataset which contains multiple features. But I'm having trouble understanding how to pad multiple features. The [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus) contains the following 3 features per row: `word`, `POS`, `shape`. Where POS is part-of-speech tagging and shape is categorical `numerical`, `lowercase`, `capitalized` etc.

So for the LSTM my timesteps need to be the same. In this case its the length of the sentence. The words I can just pad. Either by just adding `_PAD_` or something, or in the case of distributed embeddings use the min/max embedding technique.

But I don't know how to pad the additional (categorical) features. How do I pad the features `POS` and `shape`? Do I just add another category and use that for padding? If yes: in the case of embedded paddings, using the min/max embedding, would the additional padding category for the `POS` feature not train the LSTM to learn the min/max embedding on the padded POS?

An example notebook of the dataset using LSTM can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/williamroe/bi-lstm-with-crf-for-ner). Which pads the words but removes all the other features. How can I expand on this notebook, by adding POS as a feature and use padding?

Should I use one-hot encoding for the categorical values and just use a vector with zero's? If yes, how does one make a vector of zero's in python as one-hot encoding.